# What you enter in a particular form is not preserved

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

For example, what you type on Stackoverflow.com's search engine is preserved.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
if (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.key == 'F') { // F = 70
    let target = document.querySelector("#search > div > input");
    target.value = 'America';
    target.focus();
}
});
```

However, not all text areas and forms seem to be preserved.

For example, in a search engine on another Q & A site:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {

    if (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.key == 'F') { // F = 70

        let target = document.querySelector(".SearchBox_searchBox__inputBoxInput__nf3fq");
        target.value = 'America';
        target.focus();
    }
});
```

https://chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/search?p=&fr=common-navi

On certain sites, after inputting, if you do not enter the `space` key, etc. at the end, the entered characters will be deleted.

On certain sites, if you press the `ENTER` key to search after entering, the entered characters may be deleted.

I want to know the cause, when it is erased.

What is the cause?

Is there a solution?

Comment: what do you mean by `preserved`?

Comment: Whether or not the entered content is reflected.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates problem

Answer (score 1):

I think you're referring to the HTML `autocomplete` attribute, which lets the site tell the browser whether or not to provide autocompletions (which may be the "preserved search" you were referring to).

> The HTML autocomplete attribute is available on  elements that take a text or numeric value as input,  elements,  elements, and  elements. autocomplete lets web developers specify what if any permission the user agent has to provide automated assistance in filling out form field values, as well as guidance to the browser as to the type of information expected in the field.

And when you set it to `off`, eg. `<input autocomplete="off" />` ...

> The browser is not permitted to automatically enter or select a value for this field.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete

If you look at the search input at https://chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/search?p=&fr=common-navi, you'll see:

```
<input type="text" name="p" placeholder="Q&amp;Aを探す" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off" value="" data-sec="h_srch" data-slk="txt" class="SearchBox_searchBox__inputBoxInput__nf3fq">
```

Note the `autocomplete="off"` inside.